# How to run a method only after recycler View is loaded?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView. I need to fill with different types of input types so I tried putting this line after the recyclerView is made:

```
((EditText)recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(6)
.itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText))
.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

Works fine if it's done after a button click, but if just put on the onStart() method like below:

```
loadrecyclerView();  //(fills the recyclerView with items)
        ((EditText)recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(6)
.itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText))
.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

It doesn't work and sends the error code:

```
Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 2):

`RecyclerView` takes some time to draw items, they aren't ready one line after setting `adapter` or calling `notifyDataSetChanged` (or similar)

one of the ways is to wait until `RecyclerView` draw all its children, using `post`

```
recyclerView.post(
    new Runnable(){
        // code in here will fire when recyclerView finishes all its jobs
        // e.g. redrawing
    }
);
```

but its kind of hack, should be used only at least. in your case `setInputType` should be used inside `adapter` in `onCreateViewHolder` or maybe in `onBindViewHolder`, or even straight inside list item XML